# how to create a DNS SPF record with long text

Tags: dns-hosting

Our email hosting company provided a SPF records which is too long.  I can't put all into one record.  what can I do?

Thanks in advance.

David

Comment: What DNS provider or software ore you using? How many characters long is the record?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/a/929176/183318

Answer (score -1):

You can break it up into two records.

```
mail  IN  TXT  "v=spf1 ...."
mail  IN  TXT  "text continues here"
```

The two strings will be concatenated and no space will be put between.

EDIT: Håkan Lindqvist is right, one record with two strings is the right way.

```
mail  IN  TXT  "v=spf1 .." "text continues here"
```

Comment: That would make two separate records, those will not be combined. One record with two strings however...